# Correct Usage of Argparse for Subparser Subcommands

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How can I get an argparse subparser to only parse arguments for it's own arguments? It seems that calling `parse_known_args` on the subparser parses all the parent's arguments.

Given this simplified version, and the inputs `foo bar`:

```
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
main_parser.add_argument("command")
args, subc_args = main_parser.parse_known_args()
print("main parser = {}".format(args))

sub_parser = main_parser.add_subparsers()
sub_command_parser = sub_parser.add_parser("sub_command")
sub_command_parser.add_argument("hostname")

sub_args = sub_command_parser.parse_known_args()
print("sub parser = {}".format(sub_args))
```

The first print returns what I expect:

```
main parser = Namespace(command='foo')
```

Whereas the penultimate line returns the same thing, only with the extra argument as part of the "unknown" list:

```
sub parser = (Namespace(hostname='foo'), ['bar'])
```

How can I get something like `sub_command_parser.parse_known_args()` to ignore the arguments that were given before it? What I need is for `sub_args` to only contain those arguments that were added with `sub_command_parser.add_argument()`. I can call them directly afterwards like this; `sub_args[1]`, but that seems hacky and unreliable.

**Background:** I have a package split up into a main file as the entry point which handles the top level arguments, and the modules that do the actual work. I want to add a top level "main parser" in the main file, and sub-parsers in the modules.

Comment: `parse_known_args()` parses the `sys.argv[1:]` list.  It does not remove elements from that list.  Normally we call the `main_parser`, and let it call the subparser, with the remaining arguments.  You could try `sub_command_parser.parse_args(subc_args)`; that is give the first unknowns to the subparser.  And that use, don't bother with the `sub_parsers` mechanism.  Just define sub-parser.

Comment: Another way to put it - if you have multiple parsers, each will see the same `sys.argv[1:]`.  If you want to change that, either customize `sys.argv` on-the-fly, or call `parse_args` with a `argv` list.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I've posted an answer below. If you'd like to take credit ;) just post as an answer and I'll mark yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal subcommands usage, all in one file:

```
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sub_parser = main_parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
sub_command_parser = sub_parser.add_parser("sub_command")
sub_command_parser.add_argument("hostname")

args = main_parser.parse_args()
print(args)
args.command   # name of the subcommand
args.hostname   # value from subcommand argument
```

This automatically passes the remaining strings to the subparser, the named in `command`.  This usage should be clear in the Python documentation.

If you are going to split the parsers between files, and call them separately, skip `add_subparsers` bit.  It doesn't do anything for you.

```
# Main file
#
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("command")
args, subc_args = parser.parse_known_args()
print("main parser = {}".format(args.command))

# Subcommand file
#
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("hostname")
sub_args, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args(subc_args)
print("sub parser = {}".format(sub_args.hostname))
```

Comment: Yup, this is indeed what I ended up doing (skipping the subparser). The only issue with this solution is that when you use `-h` in your call to the script, even if it's after the subcommand, you'll always get back the help for the first parser since you're immediately calling `parse_known_args` before the second parser.

I'm going to use the click library instead, which is better suited for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

That helped, thanks @hpaulj. Looks like there isn't a good way to handle subcommands with argparse. The full working example for people stumbling on this is:

```
# Main file
#
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
main_parser.add_argument("command")
args, subc_args = main_parser.parse_known_args()
print("main parser = {}".format(args.command))

# Subcommand file
#
sub_parser = main_parser.add_subparsers()
sub_command_parser = sub_parser.add_parser("sub_command")
sub_command_parser.add_argument("hostname")

sub_args, unknown_args = sub_command_parser.parse_known_args(subc_args)
print("sub parser = {}".format(sub_args.hostname))
```

Note that when calling the class (or however you've implemented the subparser creation in the subcommand file), you'll need to supply the `subc_args` too, as optional.

EDIT: Specifying `add_help=False` in the main parser gets around this :)